# How can I have an inline offline plotly chart output as an image in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, plotly

I would like an image of the offline chart to be the output, rather than an interactive plot, in order for the PDF to generate nicer. e.g. replacing:

```
pl.offline.iplot(fig)
```

In the offline section of the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/offline/#reference), it says in the offline.iplot section:

> "To embed an image of the chart, use `plotly.image.ishow`."

which requires online authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to create an account and use `plotly.image.ishow`, given it doesn't save the picture on their servers.